# Cannot seem to call method in another class

Tags: c#, class

I am trying a new way to share string through different classes, but I can't seem to get this to work... Previously I made public static string, but I read that this isn't recommended etc so I am trying a new way, but unfortunately I don't know how to call this method...

This is the code I made:

```
public class AddServer
{
    public AddServer(string name, string seed, List<string> ops)
    {
        Ops = ops;
        Seed = seed;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Seed { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Ops { get; private set; } 
}
```

To be honest, I don't know if this is the right way of doing this, if it's not could someone push me into the right way? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error?  I don't see anything particularly wrong with this code

Comment: What have you tried?  The way you should call it (to my eyes) is `AddServer ads = new AddServer("name","seed",new List<string>()); ads.Name`

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The problem is that I have no idea how to set or get data ti/from it.

Comment: "I am trying a new way to share string through different classes," Can you explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I've got it fixed now :), well, what I am trying to do is to send strings and other variables to another class. But the `public string` at the top of my code makes the code unreadable after a while.

Comment: You've only shown 1/2 of the needed information.  Since your problem is how this class communicates with another we need to see both this class, and the relevant section(s) of the class that uses it to see how it is being used, and what needs to be done with it.  Without knowing how this class is used we can't know if it's designed properly or how it should be effectively used.

Comment: @Servy That was the problem, I didn't know how.

Comment: @FoxyShadoww Then you need to explain what it needs to do.  Explaining how to create an instance of this type is only helpful if this type is designed properly for the problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AddServer
{
    public AddServer(string name, string seed, List<string> ops)//constructor
    {
        Ops = ops;
        Seed = seed;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Seed { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Ops { get; private set; } 
}
```

In this case we are not calling a method from another class.  We are constructing an instance of `AddServer`.  The properties have a private set.  This makes the properties read-only to external types.  In other words, the properties can only be set in the constructor.

Create an instance of the class and pass the parameter values to set the properties.

```
List<string> operations = new List<string>() {"1", "2" };
AddServer addServer = new AddServer("nameValue", "seedValue", operations);
```

Now that the properties have values, you can access them via:

```
string nameResult = addServer.Name;
string seedresult = addServer.Seed;
List<string> opsResult = addServer.Ops
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> ops = new List<string>();
AddServer asvr = new AddServer("newName", "newSeed", ops);

Console.WriteLine(asvr.Name);
Console.WriteLine(asvr.Seed);
Console.WriteLine(asvr.Ops.Count);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Funny how stuff never works the first time you try something. Thanks!

Comment: @FoxyShadoww - You're welcome. Just as a sidenote, what is being called here is not a method but a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From another class you would:

```
//Create list of strings to pass to AddServer class's constructor method
List<string> ops = new List<string> {"ops1", "ops2", "ops3");

//Call the AddServer constructor to create a new instance of the class AddServer
AddServer myAddserver = new AddServer("server01", "some seed", lstOps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something:

```
var server = new AddServer();
server.AddServer("name", "seed", new List<string>());
```

Obviously substituting sensible values for your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a method, per se, it is a [Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ace5hbzh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

the way to call that would be:

`var addserver = new AddServer("Name","Seed",new List<string>{"asdasd","asdasd2","etc"});`